# How to not change the layout when zooming in with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and here is my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="/index.php"><img src="/images/mainstuff/logo.png"/></a>
            <p class="titreheader "> Testing stuff </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.php"><button class="bttn-slant"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> index</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/profil.php"><button class="bttn-slant"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> profil</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/forum.php"><button class="bttn-slant"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> forum</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/news.php"><button class="bttn-slant"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> news</button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/logout.php"><button class="bttn-slant"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> logout</button></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the render when I'm not zooming in :
[image: Not Zooming In]

Here is the render when I'm zooming in :
[image: Zooming In]

As you can see, the layout is all messed up. I would like that the buttons stay in place. Here is a good example of what I'm talking about: [manapot.com](http://www.manapot.com)

On this site, everything stay in place when you resize.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Don't use `col-xs-6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` queries to make some CSS settings depending on things like screen or window width. In such settings, you can e.g. set the font size to a specific small value if the window is very narrow.

May be you can font-size following like `font-size: 2vw;font-size: 3vw;font-size: 4vw;`

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/viewport-sized-typography-minimum-maximum-sizes/